# Implementing a Linked List in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

I don't understand why the following code won't work. When I append things to my LinkedList it still returns true for isEmpty() and printList() doesn't print anything. Clearly I'm messing up references but I can't figure out for the life of me where I'm messing up. If you could also point out if there's anything wrong with my design that would be great.

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data, next=None):

        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)



class LinkedList(object):



    def __init__(self):

        self.head = None
        self.size = 0


    def append(self, *data):

            n = self.head
            #new_node = Node(data)

            if self.head is None:

                n = self.head

                for elem in data:
                    n = Node(elem)
                    n = n.next
                    self.size += 1

            else:

                n = self.head
                while n.next != None:
                    n = n.next

                for elem in data:
                    n.next = Node(elem)
                    n = n.next
                    self.size += 1




    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def printList(self):

        n = self.head

        while n is not None:
            print str(n)
```

Comment: That code never assigns anything (except `None`) to `self.head`, which it should probably do at some point.

Comment: But if self.head is None it assigns Node(elem) to self.head?

Comment: No, it assigns to `n` multiple times and increments `self.size`. You never assign anything to `self.head` outside of `__init__`.

Comment: So when i assign self.head to n it only copies None and n doesn't reference self.head?

Comment: When you do `n = self.head`, you create a new local variable `n` which contains the _value_ of `self.head`. Changing `n` afterwards has absolutely no effect on the value of `self.head`.

Comment: Ok I thought it would just store a reference the same memory location! Thanks guys

Comment: No, python doesn't work this way. What does work is that you can change _attributes_ of the referenced values, e.g. if `x` is some object with an attribute `a` then doing `y = x; y.a="asd"` will also affect `x`. The same is true for containers like dict and list, `l = []; x = l; x.append(1)` will also effect `l` because both variables reference the same object. In conclusion, you can modify the thing that is referenced, but you can not change the reference (except for assigning another value to the variable whose reference you want to change).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplified your code to add only single element at a time.

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data, next=None):

        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)



class LinkedList(object):



    def __init__(self):

        self.head = None
        self.size = 0


    def append(self, data):
            if not self.head:
                n = Node(data)
                self.head = n
                return
            else:
                n = self.head

                while n.next != None:
                    n = n.next

                new_node = Node(data)
                n.next = new_node;
                return


    def isEmpty(self):
        return not self.head

    def printList(self):
        n = self.head

        while n:
            print str(n)
            n = n.next

ll = LinkedList()
elems = [1, 2, 3, 54, 6]
for elem in elems:
    ll.append(elem)

ll.printList()
```

Output:

```
>>> 
1
2
3
54
6
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.nextNode = None

    def set_and_return_Next(self):
        self.nextNode = Node()
        return self.nextNode

    def getNext(self):
        return self.nextNode

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def setData(self, d):
        self.data = d

class LinkedList:
    def buildList(self, array):
        self.head = Node()
        self.head.setData(array[0])
        self.temp = self.head
        for i in array[1:]:
            self.temp = self.temp.set_and_return_Next()
            self.temp.setData(i)
            self.tail = self.temp
        return self.head
    def printList(self):
        tempNode = self.head
        while(tempNode!=self.tail):
            print(tempNode.getData())
            tempNode = tempNode.getNext()
        print(self.tail.getData())
myArray = [3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 21]

myList = LinkedList()
myList.buildList(myArray)
myList.printList()
```

Comment: *"I don't understand why the following code won't work."* This answer does not even attempt to answer the OP's actual question.  Code without context is not helpful to someone new to programming.

Answer (score -1):

```
class LinkedList(object):
   def __init__(self,data,none):
      self.data=data
      self.none=none

  def insert(self):
```